# Error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I "

Tags: jquery, ajax

Though this problem has been asked many times. Did look into those solutions but I think mine is little different. I am getting error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I" on the below line in Console.

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
```

This script is being called on the select onchange. Below is the code for the same.

```
<label>VehicleMake:<SPAN>Write your VehicleMake</SPAN></label>
                                <?php
                                    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT(vehicle_make) FROM car_details";
                                    $query = mysql_query($sql);
                                ?>

                                <select name=country id='s1' onchange=ajaxFunction('s1');>
                                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                                    <?php while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $rs["vehicle_make"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["vehicle_make"]; ?></option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </select>
                                <label>Vehicle Model:<SPAN>Please select Vehicle Model</SPAN></label>
                                <select name=state  onchange=ajaxFunction('s2');>
                                    <option value=''>Select One</option>
                                </select>
                                <label>Vehicle Type:<SPAN>Please select Vehicle Type</SPAN></label>
                                <select name=city  onchange=ajaxFunction('s3');>
                                    <option value=''>Select One</option>
                                </select>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: do you mean the html that is generated in view source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely in the response from your server.
It probably looks like this

```
JSON.parse('{"id": "1"|"2" }');
```

which produces the same error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token |
```

Comment: Do i need to make some change to my code to fix this?

Comment: In your backend, yes - if the error is in the response.

Comment: All I am trying to do is to get value in the second select box onchange of the first select box.

Comment: Yes, but if you're getting the error on the line `var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);` then the error is somewhere else OTHER than your script and NOTHING to do with changing the select box value.

Comment: yeah, that is correct. Found the reason for the same. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Glad to help! Happy hacking! :)